# What is the difference between using nibs or liquor for making chocolate bars?

Tags: chocolate

For making chocolate bars. Nibs or liquor, why use one over the other?

Comment: Mostly because nibs are less processed so you add less processed product.

Answer (score 2):

Chocolate liquor is the result of grinding and heating cocoa nibs. It's then mixed with other ingredients to form the final chocolate. So it's not really one or the other: nibs are produced in one stage of the process, and chocolate liquor is produced at a later stage.